# Xamarin Forms - Multi-line text truncation

Tags: xamarin.forms

Truncate the label text makes it one line. App shows description, it needs to be displayed in 2-3 lines but Xamarin "**LineBreakMode=TailTruncation**" truncates it and restricts it to one line.
Is there any way to truncate label text and show in multi-lines. If text doesn't fit into n number of lines, then it should be truncated.

```
<Label LineBreakMode="TailTruncation" FontSize = "20" Text="Multi line Text" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: SO is a Q&A site.  To get a good answer, you should try to ask a good Question first.  What you're posted is a list of requirements, not a question.

Comment: It's limitation of xamarin forms as native android supports multi-line truncation. In native android we can use maxLines. If you can't answer the question, that doesn't mean it's not a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have implemented custom renderer to handle this.

http://depblog.weblogs.us/2016/06/27/xamarin-forms-multi-line-label-custom-renderer-gotcha/

```
//Droid
public class MultiLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.LayoutChange += (s, args) =>
            {
                Control.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
                Control.SetMaxLines(2);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @user12345, does this always work for you?
I've implemented the same renderer, but it doesn't longer work after having updated Xamarin.Forms on my project. I describe this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46042386/xamarin-forms-the-multilinelabel-doesnt-longer-work-on-android)

Answer (score 13):

Since Xamarin.Forms 3.3 a new property was introduced for this feature. It's called `MaxLines`.

Here is an example in C#:

```cs
var yourLabel = new Label
{
    LineBreakMode = LineBreakMode.TailTruncation,
    Text = "Your text",
    MaxLines = 2
};
```

Here is an example in XAML:

```xml
<Label
    LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
    Text="Your text"
    MaxLines="2" />
```

See https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.label.maxlines?view=xamarin-forms for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Try with custom label by using UILineBreakMode in iOS:

```
//iOS
public class CustomMultiLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
    {
         base.OnElementChanged(e);

         MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel = (MultiLineLabel)Element;

         if (multiLineLabel != null && multiLineLabel.Lines != -1)
         {
              Control.Lines = multiLineLabel.Lines;
              Control.LineBreakMode = UIKit.UILineBreakMode.TailTruncation;
         }
    }
}
```