# Xamarin.Forms: the MultiLineLabel doesn't longer work on Android

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, label, multiline, custom-renderer

On my Xamarin.Forms project, I use a **MultiLineLabel** to display a title on 1 or 2 lines, depending the text length. I'm based on this [blog](http://depblog.weblogs.us/2016/06/27/xamarin-forms-multi-line-label-custom-renderer-gotcha/) to achieve this.

So I have a `MultiLineLabel` control:

```
public class MultiLineLabel : Label
{
    private static int _defaultLineSetting = -1;

    public static readonly BindableProperty LinesProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(Lines), typeof(int), typeof(MultiLineLabel), _defaultLineSetting);
    public int Lines
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(LinesProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LinesProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

I use 2 **renderers**:

- on **iOS**, I've kept the given renderer:

  ```
  public class CustomMultiLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
  {
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);

          MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel = (MultiLineLabel)Element;

          if (multiLineLabel != null && multiLineLabel.Lines != -1)
              Control.Lines = multiLineLabel.Lines;

      }
  }
  ```
- on **Android** I've customized the renderer:

  ```
  public class CustomMultiLineLabelRenderer : LabelRenderer
  {
      protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
      {
          base.OnElementChanged(e);

          MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel = (MultiLineLabel)Element;

          if (multiLineLabel != null && multiLineLabel.Lines != -1)
          {
              Control.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
              Control.SetMaxLines(multiLineLabel.Lines);
          }
      }
  }
  ```

And I use this **MultiLineLabel** like this in **XAML**:

```
<StackLayout 
    Grid.Row="0"
    Spacing="0">

    <local:MultiLineLabel
        Margin="8,6,8,0"
        TextColor="{ DynamicResource InverseTextColor }"
        Text="{ Binding encart_titre }"
        FontSize="{ artina:OnOrientationDouble 
            Default=16,
            PortraitTablet=20,
            LandscapeTablet=20 }"
        LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"
        Lines="2"
        Grid.Column="0"
        BackgroundColor="Yellow"
    />
</StackLayout>
```

Until I used `Xamarin.Forms v.2.3.4.247`, this worked well on Android:

[image: screenshot before update]

But after having updated to the latest version (`Xamarin.Forms v.2.4.0.269-pre2`), it doesn't longer work as expected:

[image: screenshot after update]

I also tried to use the renderer given on the blog:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel = (MultiLineLabel)Element;

    if (multiLineLabel != null && multiLineLabel.Lines != -1)
    {
        Control.SetSingleLine(false);
        Control.SetLines(multiLineLabel.Lines);
    }
}
```

But I didn't get the expected rendering:
[image: screenshot after updater - alternative]

***Would you have any explanation? Or another suggestion? On iOS this works well.***

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But after having updated to the latest version (Xamarin.Forms v.2.4.0.269-pre2), it doesn't longer work as expected:

**Cause:**

I've checked the source codes of `Xamarin.Forms v.2.4.0.269-pre2`. In `LabelRenderer`'s `OnElementChange` event, `FormsTextView`'s `SetLineBreakMode` will be called which contains following codes:

```
public static void SetLineBreakMode(this TextView textView, LineBreakMode lineBreakMode)
{
    switch (lineBreakMode)
    {
        case LineBreakMode.NoWrap:
            textView.SetMaxLines(1);
            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = null;
            break;
        case LineBreakMode.WordWrap:
            textView.Ellipsize = null;
            textView.SetMaxLines(100);
            textView.SetSingleLine(false);
            break;
        case LineBreakMode.CharacterWrap:
            textView.Ellipsize = null;
            textView.SetMaxLines(100);
            textView.SetSingleLine(false);
            break;
        case LineBreakMode.HeadTruncation:
            textView.SetMaxLines(1);
            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.Start;
            break;
        case LineBreakMode.TailTruncation:
            textView.SetMaxLines(1);
            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.End;
            break;
        case LineBreakMode.MiddleTruncation:
            textView.SetMaxLines(1);
            textView.SetSingleLine(true);
            textView.Ellipsize = TextUtils.TruncateAt.Middle;
            break;
    }
}
```

As you can see, if you use `LineBreakMode.TailTruncation`, `textView.SetMaxLines(1);` and `textView.SetSingleLine(true);` will be called, which disable the multi line function.(In `2.3.4` `textView.SetSingleLine(true);` doesn't exist).

**Solution:**

To fix the problem, you simply need to add two lines of codes in your renderer:

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Xamarin.Forms.Label> e)
{
    base.OnElementChanged(e);
    MultiLineLabel multiLineLabel = (MultiLineLabel)Element;

    if (multiLineLabel != null && multiLineLabel.Lines != -1)
    {
        Control.SetSingleLine(false);
        Control.SetMaxLines(multiLineLabel.Lines);
        Control.SetLines(multiLineLabel.Lines);

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Elvis Xia thanks for your feedback. I use it without the line `Control.SetLines(multiLineLabel.Lines);` as I  want the Label auto extends depending the content.